# Разработка приложений по iOS и android - используя минимум языков программирования

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, kotlin

Коллеги, ранее разработкой мобильными приложениями не занимался.
Занимаюсь веб-разработкой, есть опыт разработки windows-приложений на C++.

Встала задача в установленные строки, реализовать мобильное приложение для iOS и Andoid, с последующим размещение в соответствующие маркетплейсы.

Приложение должно быть нативным. 
В котором будет база вопросов и ответов разбитые на категории, сложности и разбивке по другим критериям и будут иметь связи друг к другу.
Пользователю предстоит отвечать на надомные вопросы из базы, после чего, на основе правильных ответов будет вестись статистика в ЛК, количество правильных ответов, неправильных и другая подобная информация.

Также потребуется ограничить доступ к некоторому функционалу, и сделать его платным.

Изначально, я смотрел в сторону PhoneGap, но сразу понял, что адекватным образом там нельзя будет локально хранить вопросы-ответы, картинки и другую базу.

Далее начал дальше изучать, и все больше и больше встречаю разные технологии, языки, модули.
Kotlin, Swift, Java, ReactNative, NativeScript etc..  у каждого свои минусы и преимущества.

Задача уже стоит. И начинать изучать одно, по ходу работы понять, что это по какой-то причине не подходит, сами понимаете, как это все затянется.

Подскажите, какой стек технологий выбрать, чтобы минимизировать, количество технологий и языков программирования для разработки, и которыми я мог бы решить эти задачи?

Какие модули понадобятся? Как есть БД, что бы можно было спокойно работать с БД, создавать таблицы и т.д.?

Что бы не писать отдельно под каждую ОС и не погружаться сильно в специфику каждого?

С разными элементами UI на разных ОС не обращаем внимания.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Хочу сказать, что я не понимаю людей, которые минусуют этот вопрос. Он довольно серьезный, а найти адекватный непредвзятый обзор минусов и плюсов гибридных приложений, да еще и в сравнении с нативом не так то просто. Большинство обзоров рассчитаны на то как "посмотрите, я делаю Hello World за минуту" или подразумевают хорошие знания именно мобильной разработки у пользователя.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk, вот именно. Это тема для хорошего обзора, а не формата вопрос-ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Начиная с вот этого пункта:

```
Также потребуется ограничить доступ к некоторому функционалу, и сделать его платным.
```

Вам придется "погружаться сильно в специфику каждого".
Если UI и работу с базой данных еще можно сделать на Javascript, почти не погружаясь в особенности конкретной платформы, то все что хоть как-то выходит за эти рамки, потребует понимания логики работы платформ.

Теперь по сути:

- flutter.io - на данный момент, это самый перспективный кросс-платформенный фреймворк. Из минусов: вроде как, еще не все возможности нативных платформ поддерживает, и всегда остается страх что Google его забросит, как и многие другие экспериментальные платформы.
- React Native. Стабильный, есть много компонентов, огромное комьюнити. Минусы: в первую очередь рассчитан на front-end React программистов, которым понадобилось сделать еще и мобильные приложения. Т.е. надо осваивать сам React. Дополнительный минус: часть багов просто игнорируется создателями и можно потратить немало времени на костыли для обхода проблемы. Кроме того, при большом количестве компонентов высокая вероятность ада конфликтов версий компонентов.
- Ionic. Похож на React, только основан на Angular. Про проблемы не скажу, т.к. мало с ним работал.
- Xamarin. Несколько лет назад был куплен Microsoft, и с тех пор Microsoft его пытается допилить до полноценного удобного применения. Эффект пока околонулевой, мне неизвестно ни одного по настоящему крупного/известного приложения на Xamarin в продакшене. В отличие от других гибридных решений использует C# вместо Javascript. Последний раз работал с ним больше года назад и тогда это было довольно некомфортно, даже в сравнении с React.

Общий итог. Люди почему то активно ведутся на халяву в виде "сейчас по быстрому напишем за 1х времени сразу приложение и под iOS и под Android, а iOS и Android учить не придется, обойдемся Javascript/C#". В реальности учить приходится и iOS и Android, да еще и их специфические баги (и получается чаще всего 3х времени). Действительно, у опытных мобильных разработчиков написание простого приложения, почти не использующего индивидуальные особенности платформ получается быстрее, чем если бы они писали отдельно iOS и отдельно Android. Но тут ключевые слова: "у опытных мобильных разработчиков" и "почти не использующего индивидуальные особенности платформ".

В общем я крайне советую, при любом выборе хотя бы почитать про особенности платформ и как на них делаются хотя бы Hello World, и тогда уже заниматься созданием гибридного приложения. Но это мое личное мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - можно использовать Xamarin - фреймворк для создания кросс-платформенных приложений(ios, android, windows). При использовании данного фреймворка - разработка ведётся на C# + XAML. Вы в вопросе упомянули работу с Db, так вот в C# есть очень крутой фреймворк - Entity framework, он гораздо упрощает работу с Db, ибо автоматически генерирует Sql. Я бы вам мог поподробнее рассказать об этом, но думаю, что вы итак найдёте более детальную информацию в интернете

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент самый интересный фреймворк - это https://flutter.io/docs/get-started

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/309764)

Comment: @Air [Что делать, когда просят ссылки, а потом получают ссылки? дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1638/213987) - отвечать "выглядит нормально"  — из очереди проверок.

Answer (score 0):

Так как Вы упомянули С++, то можно попробовать написать общее ядро на нем и потом реализовать UI на нативе, используя бриджи/врапперы, соответственно для Apple это Swift/Objective C, для Android Java/Kotlin. При этом для работы с С++ кодом на яблоке удобнее Objective C, хотя в фаворитах сейчас Swift. Насчет преимуществ Kotlin перед Java не могу ничего сказать, но работы с С++ кодом на Андроид на порядок сложнее или по меньшей мере многодельнее.

Базу данных можно организовать также через С++, используя SQLite.

Такой подход конечно более затратный в целом, но позволяет добиться большей гибкости на сложных проектах, когда начинают возникать нюансы работы на разных платформах.